# How to calculate similarity between one item and an item set?

Tags: c#, recommendation-engine

Suppose a user listens n songs from my website; I need an algorithm or a method (using .net C# How?) so that I can recommend k similar songs to the user.

Comment: Are you working with genres for your songs? Than you can compare on that.

Comment: See "collaborative filtering" method

Comment: Note sure if this is what something you are looking for (A media recommentation engine) http://mymediaproject.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the scenario is that a user is browsing an item(listening to a song in your case) and you want to check which are the other similar item, to the item being browsed/listened, from a list of items. There are two approaches to make a recommendation. You can either use content based approach i.e you can suggest items with similar features (such as genre,artist etc) to the item in question or you can use collaborative filtering approach where you have to find similar users based on the rating pattern(assuming you have the rating database). You have provided no details so it is just a general explanation I am giving you.
Now coming to the recommendation part, looking at your question and the information you have provided, it is really hard to tell you what kind of approach you should take. If you have registration or rating facility and then you should follow collaborative approach else you can use content based approach. 
You can check this link below of a basic recommendation system in c#:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221865/Collaborative-Filters-How-to-build-a-recommendatio